# Why are usernames and images not shown?

Tags: java, slack, slack-api

I implemented a slash command, which creates group direct messages (mpim). It was working fine for some time, but now usernames and images of participants are not shown after the chat is created.

[image: broken usernames and images]

Is there a way to fix this by using the API differently? Or do I need some configuration change? I suspect this started when connected our workspace to others and started using shared channels, but I'm not sure. Also, all the participants of the screenshoted conversation are in the same workspace/organisation.

EDIT:

I'm using [a github project called slack-api](https://github.com/allbegray/slack-api/) to retrieve a list of users and create the mpim like this:

```
        Channel channelInfo = this.slackClient.getChannelInfo(channelId);
        List<String> userIds = channelInfo.getMembers();
        (...)
        Group group = slackClient.openMultipartyDirectMessageChannel(userIds);
```

The library version I'm using is v1.2.0.RELEASE, which is outdated. If you think this could be the cause, I try moving to the latest.

EDIT 2:

Looking at [the code here](https://github.com/allbegray/slack-api/blob/master/src/main/java/allbegray/slack/webapi/method/mpim/MpimOpenMethod.java) and [here](https://github.com/allbegray/slack-api/blob/master/src/main/java/allbegray/slack/webapi/SlackWebApiClientImpl.java#L1232), they seem to call `POST https://slack.com/api/mpim.open` sending a comma separated list of userids as `users`.

Comment: I guess those are user mentions? Please show the code that is creating them. Could be that you are using an outdated syntax.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken: I added info on how I create the mpim and which lib I use. I'll try to update to the latest version.

Comment: Can you post the code from the library that is creating the actual message? I suspect is relates to format change for user mentions by Slack, but it's hard to say without any code. Here is the official docu from Slack on the change: https://api.slack.com/changelog/2017-09-the-one-about-usernames

Comment: @ErikKalkoken: I edited once again, describing how the library creates the mpim. I also read through the blog post regarding the new mention syntax. In fact I also still use `<@...|...>` to mention people, which seems to be working, but I will change this too.

Comment: Another thing I noticed: After some time the user images and names appear.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using the 1.7.0 release? Looks like there have been quite a few changes in the five major releases since 1.2.0

Comment: Also, as you mentioned that 'after some time the names appear' - this may just be a temporary problem with the Slack API, it was mentioned in a tweet on November 11th https://twitter.com/slackhq/status/1154402079135477760?lang=en

Comment: Hey @Tom, thanks for the tips. Yes, I upgraded to 1.7.0 but see the same behaviour. The tweet is also very interesting! I will respond to it, telling them we still have the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out, this seems to be a problem on Slack's end. See https://twitter.com/slackhq/status/1197903786435584001

[image: Slack on Twitter]